# Data Source Menu In ASP.NET 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, drop-down-menu, menu, datasource

In visual studio 2010 when you create a windows application there is a menu at the top called Data, in that menu there is a option to show data sources. I can't find this is asp web app.

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to do this several different ways, and I'm afraid to say that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the keyboard shortcut Shift+Alt+D ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, and it opens debugger. Thanks for your input. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: From what I can tell, this is not going to be possible in an ASP.NET application. After enabling the toolbar that contains the "Show Data Sources" button, it is greyed out, and appears that there is no way to enable it.

Comment: I would like to think that Microsoft would have added this to ASP.NET projects.